# I am trying to set default value of checkboxes to false, no check boxes should be selected by default, user needs to select

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to set default value of checkboxes to false, no check boxes should be selected by default, user needs to select.

In the below code it diplays two check boxes one driving license number and the other one rc number, by default one is selecting, the user needs to select the checkboxes, not by default.

```
<ion-list no-lines>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let user of Types ">
        <div item-end>
            <img class="avataricon" src="assets/imgs/userr.png"></div> 
           <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="user.checked" checked="false" item-start formControlName="type" (click)="checkBoxSelect(user.checked,user)"></ion-checkbox>
           <p item-start>{{user.type}}</p>

           <ion-item  *ngIf="ShowDl"> 
              <ion-label >Driving Licence Num:</ion-label> 
            <ion-input clearInput clearOnEdit="false"  formControlName="type"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item *ngIf="ShowRc"> 
              <ion-label>RC Num:</ion-label> 
            <ion-input clearInput clearOnEdit="false" formControlName="type"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
       <ion-label item-start>
        <img class="avataricon" src="assets/imgs/userr.png">{{user.name}}</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="user.checked" item-end (click)="checkBoxSelect(user.checked,user)">
</ion-checkbox>

    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="user.checked" checked="false" item-start
 formControlName="type"
 (click)="checkBoxSelect(user.checked,user)"></ion-checkbox>
```

Probably your `user.checked` is returns true. Meaning is if `[(ngModel)]="user.checked"` is true `checked="false"` does not mean anything `ngModel` has priority.